# Solving system of polynomial matrix equations in sympy

Tags: sympy

I would like to use sympy to solve for a vector that satisfies a set of quadratic and linear equations, such as `x.T @ A @ x = x.T @ B @ x = 1`, and `x.T @ C = 0`. Here is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.polys.polymatrix import PolyMatrix
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.solvers import solve_poly_system

x = PolyMatrix([symbols(f'x{k}') for k in range(2)])
A = np.eye(2)
B = np.array([1, 0]).reshape([2, 1])
one = PolyMatrix([1])

solve_poly_system([x.T @ A @ x - one, x.T @ B], [symbols(f'x{k}') for k in range(2)])
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
PolynomialError: non-commutative expressions are not supported
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `solve` instead of `solve_poly_system`:

```
>>> solve([x.T @ A @ x - one, x.T @ B], [symbols(f'x{k}') for k in range(2)])
[(0.0, -1.0), (0.0, 1.0)]
```